# Why can't I access the attributes of this BackboneJS model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm new to BackboneJS. I'm trying to build a model and view, understanding how they work as I build them.

If I create my model like this:

```
    const VideoViewerModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
      defaults: {
        video: '',
        title: '',
        description: ''
      }
    })

const videoModel = new VideoViewerModel;
```

I get get this in my console:

```
videoModel.attributes
{video: '', title: '', description: ''}
```

But I I create it like this:

```
const VideoViewerModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: function () {
    return {
      video: '',
      title: '',
      description: ''
    }
  }
})

const videoModel = new VideoViewerModel;
```

I get this in my console:

```
videoModel.attributes
{}
```

Why am I getting two different results?

Comment: I get the same result - `{video: '', title: '', description: ''}` - with both examples.

Comment: @76484 Thanks for checking it. I can't figure out why I'm still getting the two separate results.